# create img elements with php, source=variable cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, createelement

How to create image elements with php and the source is a cookie i have set earlier?
I got some code, but it seems not working... Nothing is happening when i refresh the page.

I got a javascript code that set the first cookie to link1 with a value that is wrote in the top input box, and next cookie sets to link2 and so on.

My goal is to output 4 image elements if i have 4 "link cookies" set.

Here's what i got so far.

```
<form>
    <input id="link" type="text" placeholder="länk address">
    <input id="image" type="text" placeholder="bild address">
    <button onClick="createLink();">Lägg till länk</button>
</form>
 <?php
    for ($x = 1; isset($_COOKIE["link.$x."]); $x++) {
         $_COOKIE["link.$x."] = $link;
         $_COOKIE["image.$x."] = $image;
         echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is the array index supposed to be in the format `link.1.` and `image.1.`, or `link1` and `image1`? If the latter, change `"link.$x."` to `"link$x"` or `"link".$x` and it should hopefully, pending you actually created the cookies, solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignments are backwards. You want to read the cookie, not set the cookie. Also, you don't use `.` if you're interpolating a variable inside a string, only when you're concatenating strings.

```
for($x=1; isset($_COOKIE["link$x"]); $x++){
     $link = $_COOKIE["link$x"];
     $image = $_COOKIE["image$x"];
     echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
}
```